# How to create React useState hook matching to JSON object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-state

I am trying to create a useState hook matching to this object:

```
[
   {
      "id":"",
      "name":""
   }
]
```

This is how my code is looking like:

```
  const [ galleries, setGalleries ] = useState([
    {
      id: "",
      name: ""
    }
  ])
```

```
setGalleries({...galleries, id: gallery.id, name: gallery.name})
```

Comment: are you trying to update the existing object or add a new object?

Comment: Add a new object. I am trying to create an array with a bunch of objects matching that type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can add a new object to the state array

```
setGalleries((previousGalleries) => [...previousGalleries, {
  id: gallery.id,
  name: gallery.name
}])
```

---

Problem in your code

```
setGalleries({...galleries, id: gallery.id, name: gallery.name})
```

`galleries` is an array but you're spreading it in an object. A separate object is also not created for adding the new gallery.